# What is the recommended practice for sharing similar linq to entities expression logic in different repositories

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, repository-pattern

When using the repository pattern , sometimes you have the same logic that appears in different repositories.In the example below **GetTempEmployees()** in EmployeeRepository and **GetCompaniesWithTemps**() in CompanyRepository
have the same expressions

```
e.IsTemp && e.IsDeleted == false
```

My question is what is the recommended practice for minimizing this duplication of expression logic.

eg.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public bool IsTemp { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; } 

}

public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext()
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
}


public class EmployeeRepository
{
    private readonly TestContext _context;
    EmployeeRepository(TestContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public ICollection<Employee> GetTempEmployees()
    {
        return _context.Employee.Where(e => e.IsTemp && e.IsDeleted==false).ToList();
    }
}

public class CompanyRepository
{
    private readonly TestContext _context;
    CompanyRepository(TestContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public ICollection<Company> GetCompaniesWithTemps()
    {
        return _context.Company.Where(c => c.Employees.Any(e => e.IsTemp && e.IsDeleted == false)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution proposed by Rawling will work. Another solution would be to provide extensions working over IQueryables. Something like:

```
static class PersonSetExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Person> WhereTempAndNotDeleted(this IQueryable<Person> set)
    {
        return set.Where(x => x.IsTemp && !x.IsDeleted);
    }
}
```

Which can be used in your code as:

```
return _context.Employee
               .WhereTempAndNotDeleted()
               .ToList();
```

Comment: This is what I suggested last time I answered a question similar to this :)

Comment: this seems like a good solution too but how will you use this method for collection queries eg .Any((e => e.IsTemp && e.IsDeleted == false)

Comment: Turn the expression around! `_context.Company.Where(x => x.Employees.WhereTempAndNotDeleted().Any()).ToList();`

Comment: I have tried this after changing to  x => x.Employees.AsQueryable().WhereTempAndNotDeleted().Any() and I am getting error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1

Comment: Because you're making a call to AsQueryable. There is no SQL representation for this call and therefore EF will fail. Remove the call since its unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have to use an [`Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx), e.g.

```
static class EmployeeExpressions
{
    public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Employee, bool>>
        IsTempAndNotDeleted = e => e.IsTemp && !e.IsDeleted;
}
```

You can then use it as

```
...
return _context.Employee
    .Where(EmployeeExpressions.IsTempAndNotDeleted)
    .ToList();

...
return _context.Company
    .Where(c => c.Employees.Any(EmployeeExpressions.IsTempAndNotDeleted))
    .ToList();
```

but I'm a little hazy on this, so give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: this seems interesting let me try it

Comment: this  works if use the AsQueryable extension on the collection _context.Company.Where(c => c.Employees.AsQueryable().Any(EmployeeExpressions.IsTempAndNotDeleted)).ToList();